When hooking using Frida, the onLeave callback function does not work in offset of calling function instruction.What's the reason?
First of all, I apologize for my English skills.
i'm hooking a simple example through frida. However, there was a problem in progress, but my skills are not good, so I don't know what to search for and get through. If you know the answer, you can let me know, or I'm asking if there are any keywords I can search for.
The questions are below.
When using interceptor.attach among frida commands, both onEnter and onLeave work normally in the offset of calling function instruction(For example, the location of a instruction such as call <functionion_name> or jmp <functionion_name>. hereafter referred to as "function location").
However, onLeave does not work on any instruction offset other than offset of calling function instruction(hereafter referred to as "non-function location"), I would like to ask if there is a way to find out why.
The hooking target is the file at the following URL.
github.com/codeengn/codeengn-challenges/raw/main/RCE_Basic/...
And this is the code I used.
var funcloc = Module.getExportByName('KERNEL32.dll','GetDriveTypeA')
var Base = Module.findBaseAddress('01.exe');
var interloc = Base.add(0x1021); 
console.log(Base); 
console.log(Instruction.parse(ptr(interloc)).toString()); 

Interceptor.attach(interloc, {
   onEnter(args) { 
      console.log('onEnter');     
      var reg = this.context;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reg, 0, 2)); 
      console.log(reg.eax); 
      reg.eax = ptr('0x3')        
   },onLeave(retval) {     
      console.log('onLeave');     
      var reg = this.context;     
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reg, 0, 2));        
   } 
});

To recreate the problem, use the 01.js file that contains the above code and the 01.exe file in the link to run the following command.
frida -l C:\Users\lapla\Documents\codeengn\01.py C:\Users\lapla\Documents\codeengn\01.exe

Like the code, I implemented the onEnter and onLeave callback functions in the attach function. If the code works as I expected, whether the attach position is a function or not, the onEnter function will be executed just before the instruction at that location is executed, and the onLeave function will be executed after it is executed. And I thought that the console.log of each callback function would tell if it was executed or not.
But it didn't work as I expected.
As shown in the "non-function location hooking" image below, when hooking for a non-function position, console.log located in the onLeave function was not output.
However, when I hooked the getDriveTypeA function of kernel32.dll, I was able to confirm through console that the onLeave function worked.
I'm in a state of confusion as to why this difference occurs, and I want to figure out the cause.
Output image for non-function location hooking
I was able to check the output of the onEnter function when hooking to the nonfunction position, but not the output of the onLeave function. "Nothing" on the image indicates where the output statement would have been if the onLeave had been output normally.
non-function location hooking
[Local::01.exe]-> onEnter
{
    "pc": "0x401021",
    "sp": "0x19ff74",
    "eax": "0x2",
    "ecx": "0x560000",
    "edx": "0x560000",
    "ebx": "0x2df000",
    "esp": "0x19ff74",
    "ebp": "0x19ff80",
    "esi": "0x401001",
    "edi": "0x401000",
    "eip": "0x401021"
}
0x2

Output image for function location hooking
I was able to check the output of the onEnter and onLeave functions when I hooked to the function position, and I guessed that it worked normally.
function location hooking
[Local::01.exe]-> onEnter
{
    "pc": "0x77196900",
    "sp": "0x19ff6c",
    "eax": "0x1",
    "ecx": "0x8d0000",
    "edx": "0x8d0000",
    "ebx": "0x260000",
    "esp": "0x19ff6c",
    "ebp": "0x19ff80",
    "esi": "0x401000",
    "edi": "0x401000",
    "eip": "0x77196900"
}
0x1
onLeave
{
    "pc": "0x77196900",
    "sp": "0x19ff70",
    "eax": "0x3",
    "ecx": "0x8d0000",
    "edx": "0x8d0000",
    "ebx": "0x260000",
    "esp": "0x19ff70",
    "ebp": "0x19ff80",
    "esi": "0x401000",
    "edi": "0x401000",
    "eip": "0x77196900"
}

non-function location on disassembler
This image is a display of the non-function position in the disassembler. The same phenomenon occurs not only in the indicated positions, but also in all other non-function positions.
non-function location on disassembler
I also checked about frida docs and it may not have been confirmed because my English is not good, but I couldn't find the contents. I don't even know how to search because I have little knowledge. Is there a way to know the cause?
